# an algorithm to uncompress string

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a string like the following aa4bccc3d, and I needed to convert it to aabbbbcccddd
My solution works but I don't know how to recover a case like that:
a25b which should be decoded to abbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb or 125b case.

```
string convert(string c) {

    string result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) {
        if (c[i] >= 'a' && c[i] <= 'z') {
            result += c[i];
        } else if (c[i]-'0' >= 0 && c[i]-'0' <= 9) {
            if (i < c.size()) {
                int prevI = i;
                int nextJ = i;
                if (c[++nextJ] >= 'a' && c[++nextJ] <= 'z') {
                    for (int j = 0; j < c[prevI]-'0'; j++ {
                        result += c[prevI+1];
                    }    
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You can't. What if the string was `a55b`? Okay, your code seems to assume the input was all alphabet..

Comment: Instead of your "if" checking for a number, you need to be more sophisticated there, checking for numeric digits, extracting the string, converting it to an integer and using that as the count.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  it shoudl be a followed fifty five b

Comment: it is as an array c[i]

Comment: @1sand0s: [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>

std::string convert( const std::string &s )
{
    const char *p = s.c_str();

    std::string t;
    t.reserve( s.size() );

    while ( *p )
    {
        if ( std::isdigit( *p ) )
        {
            char *q;
            long int n = std::strtol( p, &q, 10 );
            p = q;
            if ( *p )
            {
                t.append( n, *p );
                ++p;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            t += *p++;
        }
    }

    return t;
}

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "a25b" ); 

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << convert( s ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
a25b
abbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

If instead of `a25b` to initialize s with `aa4bccc3d` then the output is

```
aa4bccc3d
aabbbbcccddd
```

You could also include in the function code that will precisely calculate how much memory should be reserved for the result string before forming it.

Comment: Where you say if (*p) tho', isn't that really the way to test for booleans, and null checks should be compared to NULL ,and integer checks for zero compared to 0? I mean while we're being purists :-)

Comment: This is far from idiomatic. I can't even begin to think why he is working with a `const char*` instead of the `std::string` value itself.

Comment: This is great.  I'd love to see something that an idiom like me could learn some c++ from.  But all the vertical space in the code.  All the scrolling... Think of the children

Comment: what about an O(N) solution :) ? if we assume that append is another iteration...

Comment: @Jefffrey  At first I thought that it is the C section of SO.:) So I started do the task in C.

Comment: @1sand0s: This form is quite idomatic. It's definitely not a null pointer check, so `NULL` is conceptually wrong. Using C++'s `nullptr` would have made `*p == nullptr` an error. `0` is an integer, not a char. The literal for a null char is `'\0'`.

Comment: moderator busted my chops for posting a C example which I deleted, because he cited my code as not being idiomatically C++ enough. Hence my comment about this being (more) idiomatic. I will now delete that comment too :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> //max
#include <locale> //isdigit

std::string uncompress(const std::string & s) {
    int counter=0;
    std::string r;
    for(char c : s){
        if(std::isdigit(c)){
            counter=counter*10+c-'0';
        }
        else{
            for(int i=0;i<std::max(1,counter);++i ){
                r=r+c;
            }
            counter=0;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    std::cout << uncompress("aa12c") << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```